# How to offset the API results from Azure devops, not returning offset

Tags: javascript, azure, url, devops

I'm trying to get all the build and pipeline data from our Azure devops account.

This is done through an API request.
I have hundreds of builds for some pipelines so I wanted to limit the results to 25 at a time.

I have added to the API URL the parameters using 'top' and 'skip'. However I still only ever get the first 25 results back.

Here is my request:

```
response = await axios.get(
  `https://dev.azure.com/name/${projectName}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.1-preview.7&$top=${returnNumber}&$skip=10`,
  {
    headers: headers, // Pass headers as an object
  }
);
```

The return number is 25. I wanted to have the skip number as a variable as well. but stuck it to 10 for testing.

Maybe this just cant be done with Azure devops. I am not an expert at all.
I have tried changing some of the key words and trying 'limit' and 'offset' to change the variables.

Does anyone know why this wont work or if it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use `$top` along with a `continuationToken`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0